# css "background-image" shows unwanted border, img "src" does not

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Getting started with Twitter Bootstrap, I ran into a strange problem of which I can't figure out the cause.

When I render an image using:

```
<img class="img-rounded" id="logo" />
```

and in CSS:

```
#logo {
    background-image: url(/Content/Images/logo.png);
}
```

The image is shown with a narrow 'border':

[image: Bordered]

Even though I can't find anything remotely related to this effect. The corners are open because of the `img-rounded` class.

Rendering the image using:

```
<img class="img-rounded" id="logo" src="~/Content/Images/SO.png" />
```

Renders as expected:

[image: NoBorder]

How can I get rid of the border?
CSS code I've tried without success:

- `border: none;`
- `color: blue;`
- `background-color: blue;`
- `border-style: none;`

Comment: Why would you insert a background-image on an image?

Comment: `border-style:none`?

Comment: Are trying to achieve something like this? [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/55fqc6bp/1) As using image as `background-image` on an `<img>` tag wasn't a great idea.

Comment: @rblarsen Good question. I had a <div> originally, but seeing a Bootstrap sample, I decided to change it to <img> which makes no sense at all keeping the same css. I've changed it to a <div> again and it works fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is not to use an `<img>` tag and try to set a `background-image` in css.

Either use a `<div>` or `<img src="pic.png">` and not an invalid mix of both.

Credits to rblarsen who pointed this out.

Answer (score 14):

This should work. I believe the problem is to do with the `img` tag used without the `src` attribute. In that case, we can simply use a `div` tag.

I have come across this problem earlier on SO, I do not remember the link to that question though.

1) Make your `height` and `width` as 0.

2) Give appropriate padding as per the image size. (i.e padding: width/2px height/2px width/2px height/2px )

In short your left and right padding should add upto `width` of the image
AND
your top and bottom padding should add upto `height` of the image.

```css
img {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C4wK.png) no-repeat;
    font-size:0;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    padding:36px 99px 36px 99px; /* Since height and width are 0. use appropriate padding. Image is of 197 X 73 dimension. So using 36px on left and right whereas 99px each on top and bottom*/
    border-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<img />
```

Answer (score 3):

For people running into this situation, the **actual** solution to the problem in question (as opposed to people telling you "just don't do that") is to set the `src` of the image to a blank image; preferably a `1x1` image to reduce load size, and optionally even as an incorporated `base64` URI to eliminate the additional HTTP request (depending on which solution is more appropriate).

So from the OP's example, the altered code:

```html
<img class="img-rounded" id="logo" src="/images/blank.gif" />
```

or

```html
<img class="img-rounded" id="logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just add this**, hope it'll work well

```
#logo {
    background-image: url(/Content/Images/logo.png);
    border-radius:0px;
    border:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using the image as a background. Why not set it as the src property of the button

```
<input src="images/submit-bkg.png" id="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" type="image" value="" tabindex="2"/>
```

When you set the type as image the input expects an src attribute as well..

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-src and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1

Comment: I have different themes, using css files to change for example this logo. I don't want to move the logic to the markup to set the correct src.