# grey border surrounding image

Tags: html, css

I have a Bootstrap table on the view and the last 2 columns are images. I load the table once the Ajax call is successful.

**Issue**

[image]

when table id populated with data, I see grey border and nothing makes sense. I don't have any code which specifies border.
Below is my CSS Code

```
img {
    border:none;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.assign {
    background: url(Images/user_not_assigned.png) no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

I added blue dashed border to the image to make sure it overrides. I see the blue dashed border along with grey border

[image]

**CSS**

```
img {
    border : 2px blue dashed;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.assign {
    background: url(Images/user_not_assigned.png) no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

HTML View:

```
<div id="getorder" class="table-responsive" data-request-url="@Url.Action("GetPendingOrders", "Main")">
    <table id="editorder" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <caption><h4 class="chocolatetext"><strong>Pending / Assigned Orders</strong></h4></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>COL1 #</th>
                <th>COL2 #</th>
                <th>COL3 #</th>
                <th>Assign</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="assignorder" data-request-url="@Url.Action("AssignOrder", "Main")">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/main.js")
```

Jquery Code to load table

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: peningorderurl,
    traditional: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var table = $("table");
        table.find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); //remove all previous rows if needed
        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            var tr = $("<tr class='clickable-row' data-href=" + element.id + " data-row=" + element.orderno + "></tr>");
            table.append(tr);
            var td = $("<td>" + element.id + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);
            var td = $("<td class='testno'>" + element.testno + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);
            var td = $("<td class='screenno'>" + element.screenno + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);
            var assignimage = ('<img class="assign assignselected" alt:"Assign Image" />');
            if (element.assigned == true) {
                assignimage = ('<img class="assigned assignselected" alt:"Assign Image" />');
            }
            var td = $("<td>" + assignimage + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);
            assignimage = ('<img class="no-testresults editselected" alt:"Update Test Results" />');
            var td = $("<td>" + assignimage + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);
        });
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Ajax failed:");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

**Question**

How do I remove this grey border? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hey put HTML code also or create jsfiddle

Comment: @priya_singh added the html code and JS code

Comment: wats the solution @user6747972 ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your table CSS to:

```
table {
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still get the grey border. grey border is coming from JQuery or Bootstrap css as I do not have anything written to include grey border

Answer (score 0):

add `border` `0` on table

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be background colour coming through?

```
td {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using exact specificity for that vs just targeting the table, so try this:

```
table thead > tr > th { border: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks @kawnah Issue didn't get resolved. I will remove the Image and than see if I can add another image.

Comment: Do me a favor and try one more thing...in your HTML on line 2 get rid of the class `table-striped` so it just is `<table id="editorder" class="table table-hover">`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally figured it out. The combination of an `img` Tag and the `background` property causes this issue. Either use the `img` tag with `src=` or use another tag.

Answer found here: [css "background-image" shows unwanted border, img "src" does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145014/css-background-image-shows-unwanted-border-img-src-does-not)